# iOS Development: Does automatch always timeout around five minutes of waiting?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, gamekit, game-center

I've noticed that when I leave my app searching for an automatch, it stops searching around five minutes.  Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would dismiss by itself.. I suspect that it is due to the condition dismissWitherror..